# Can not locate a "canvas" element using "canvas [id* = 'canvas_ganttChart']" CSS selector

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to locate this dynamic element(the last chars of its id change from time to time) using selenium:

```
<canvas id="canvas_ganttChart0_1" height="34" width="5371" 500;position:relative;height:34px;width:1281px"="" style="width: 5371.73400959567px;"></canvas>
```

When I used Xpath:

```
webdriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'canvas_ganttChart')]")
```

It worked.

But when I used css selector instead:

```
webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("canvas[id*='canvas_ganttChart']")
```

Console window told me canvas[id*='canvas_ganttChart'] is either an invalid css selector or it does not result in a WebElement.

Strangely enough, if I used the following css selector:

```
webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("canvas[id='canvas_ganttChart0_1']")
```

This element could be successfully found. So this "*" symbol must have made all the difference.

Can anyone spot the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What browser is it on?

Comment: It is Firefox 34.0.5

Comment: There's garbage in the middle of the attribute list following the `id` attribute, but I don't think that could be the problem. What if you used `^=` instead of `*=`?

Comment: @BoltClock, I tried using both ^= and *=, neither was working. Thank you for bringing it up.